# GWT: stange import collision error in visualisation api

Tags: java, gwt, import

I'm attempting to add two charts to a gwt page using the visualization api, but for some strange and inexplicable reason, eclipse claims that the following two imports are colliding - which makes no sense to me.

In the methods where i am calling them, I have even tried using the fully qualified names, but that doesnt seem to help either. Any idea what may be going on ?

```
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.Table.Options;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.LineChart.Options;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully qualifying one of the class names should work, or just importing `LineChart` and referencing `LineChart.Options` for example.

Can you post the code you used that didn't `import` both classes, maybe there was a problem there.